# How to profile a stored procedure DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, profiling, db2

I need a website or application that I can use to profile a stored procedure in a DB2 database.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need IBM Data Studio http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/